# jquery: события на уничтоженных объектах

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

подскажите пожалуйста, если я на какой-то объект подвесил событие

```
$('').on('', function(){});
```

потом объект удалил

Будет ли удалено событие?
И если я создам потом новый объект и новое событие - будет ли только одно событие?

**P.S.**

кажется события не удаляются и могут вызываться по нескольку (например, нажатия)

тогда вопрос такой - а как удалить элементы и события вместе с ними

Я делал так:

```
$('.box').empty();
```

Comment: да. да. *(3 символа нужно...)*

Comment: @Igor, а как и все события снести, которые привязаны к удаляемым объектам?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: _кажется события не удаляются и могут вызываться по нескольку_ - приведи пример своего кода и как ты это проверял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

До jQuery 3 версии:

```
$('.el').unbind("click");   // jQuery до 3 версии
```

После jQuery 3 версии:

```
$('.el').off("click");  // jQuery 3+
```

И помоему если написать так то оно удалит элемент и все события привязанные к нему:

```
$('.el').remove();
```

Comment: чем unbind отличается от off?

Comment: Начиная с jQuery 3.0, .unbind () устарел. Он был заменен методом .off () с jQuery 1.7, поэтому его использование уже было обескуражено.
Обработчики событий, связанные с .bind (), можно удалить с помощью .unbind (). В простейшем случае без аргументов .unbind () удаляет все обработчики, прикрепленные к элементам.

Comment: Если он был заменен еще в 1.7 почему в ответе _до 3 версии_?

Comment: Там сказано что он. Устарел с 3.0 но с 1.6 уже стало ясно что с ним есть проблемы. В 3.0 ему нашлась замена.

Comment: Так почему до 3? а не до 1.7? Какие с ним проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

> кажется события не удаляются и могут вызываться по нескольку - приведи
>   пример своего кода и как ты это проверял – Grundy 1 час назад

Пока приводил код ответа понял в чем дело

```
$('.box').on('click', '.btn-inc', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('my-data');  
    var value = parseInt($('#my_' + id).val());

    value ++;

    $('#my_' + id).val(value);
});
```

Всё дело в том, что все обработчики висят на родителе `.box`, поэтому нужен такой код:

```
$('.box').unbind();
$('.box').empty();
```

И всё работает, вопрос лишь в том, не удаляю ли я что-то дополнительное.
Например я хочу удалить обработчики только для `.btn-inc`

**P.S.**

Ну и решение именно конкретного случая - поскольку обработчик висит на родителе, нечего его вообще создавать/удалять, он должен быть создан всего один раз и использоваться дальше как есть.

**P.P.S.**

Но вообще для интереса интересно - как удалить в данной ситуации обработчики только для `.btn-inc`, когда событие отлавливается у родителя.

Comment: `off`, так же как и `on` может принимать селектор и конкретный обработчик который надо удалить [.off( events \[, selector \] \[, handler \] )](http://api.jquery.com/off/#off-events-selector-handler)